# A polynomial ring embedding

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How to prove that embedding (here F is an arbitrary algebraically closed field) $F[x_1$, $\ldots$, $x_n]$ into $F(x_1$, $\ldots$, $x_m)$ exists if and only if $n \leq m$?

The hint in the book I'm reading now was to calculate how grows the dimension of $W_n$ (here $W_n$ denotes the subspace of all polynomials with degree $\leq n$) and the dimension of its image under embedding.  But I haven't any ideas about how can it help...

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you mean to use two different notation $F[x_1,\dots,x_n],$ which usually means a polynomial rings, and $F(x_1,\cdots,x_m),$ which is usually the field of fractions for the ring $F[x_1,\cdots,x_m]$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, my question is about embedding polynomials into rational functions.

Comment: Yeah, what $W_n$ means in the rational functions is a bit odd. The usual definition of degree there yields infinite dimensional $W_n$ and if $W_n$ is really just counting the polynomials in $F(x_1,\cdots,x_m)$ then that doesn't seem useful, since the images of the embedding might not be in the polynomials, unless you can prove that they are always polynomials in the image.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I've corrected my question: now the phrase about $W_n$ is exactly the same as in the book.

Comment: One direction is trivial. For the other, suppose $n > m$ and think about where you could possibly map $x_n$ (or $x_{m+1}$) under such an embedding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use different indeterminates, for better clarity. Suppose you have an embedding
$$
\varphi\colon F[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to F(y_1,\dots,y_m)
$$
Then this can be uniquely extended to an embedding
$$
\hat{\varphi}\colon F(x_1,\dots,x_n)\to F(y_1,\dots,y_m)
$$
and the image has [transcendence degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_degree) $n$ over $F$. Since $F(y_1,\dots,y_m)$ has transcendence degree $m$, it follows that $n\le m$.

See [a paper by Yifan Wu](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~wuyifan/ExpositoryArticles/LinearAlgebraicGroups/Transcendence_Degree.pdf) for proofs (or a good algebra book).

Comment: Thank you very much!